# how can I assign the text of programatically created label to the other label in html body?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

RadioButton rb;
       Label lb;

```
   while (reader.Read())
   {
       rb = new RadioButton();   **//radio buttuns created**   
       lb = new Label();         **// labels created**

       lb.Text = reader[0].ToString(); *// each label's text assigned*
       rb.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "getSelectedAuthor('"+lb.Text.ToString()+"')");
       PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(rb);   *//when the radio clicked,function called*
       PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb);    *// to set use the text of label*
       PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

  }
  conAuthorTbl.Close();
```

*//innerthtml does not work for the purpose,//becuse I need to send//Labe2's text to other page, //when I use Response.Redirect(..), //there are no string coming //from Label2*

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function getSelectedAuthor(text) {
                    document.getElementById("Label2").innerText = text;
                }
</script>
```

*//the text where I want to set the text*

```
   <div>

            <asp:Label ID="Label2"  runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your question leaves a lot to the imagination. If you are using Response.Redirect, then you could append the value of the RadioButton to the QueryString to be used on the redirected page.

Comment: You have to set Label Text property from server side not client side.

Comment: I used Response.Reditect correctly,but it doesnt work .The problem is there is no string belonging Label2

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest you use something like knockout.js ? Its client side MVVM, you can use declarative bindings to achieve the task. I hope this helps.

http://knockoutjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function getSelectedAuthor(text) {
                    document.getElementById("<%=Label2.ClientID%>").innerText = text;
                }
</script>
```

This will work as long as the javascript is on the same aspx page.

If you need to wirk with it in external JS file, then you can create a mapping for your js file.

so you'll put something like this in your aspx page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var myElement_Label2 = getElementById("<%=Label2.ClientID%>");
  etc...
</script>
```

and then in our external js file you can work just with those references like:

```
myElement_Label2.innerText = "something";
```

Comment: it changes the text ,but when I write something like Response.Redirect("Default4.aspx"+"?variable="+Label2.Text.ToString()) in button click event to send text of Label2,I see Label2 Text does not go to the Default4.aspx , I retrieve nothing there

Comment: Client id of the element is valid always only on the currently generated page. You cannot be sure, that the client id will not change after refresh.
Also, it depends where are you calling the redirect. Is it after init() ?

Also your original question has nothing about redirect, that's a different story.